# How can I modify my Labels to make them transparent?

Tags: user-interface, tkinter, python-3.6

I have a Tkinter GUI that looks like the following:

[image: My GUI]

As you can see, the labels have a background color that doesn't look very neat with the background image. I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31730201/tkinter-label-background) that I could change the labels to text objects to get rid of the background color, but I am unsure how to do that.

Does anyone know a way I can get the text on my GUI have a transparent background? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You'll need to show some code. There are many ways to generate the GUI you've shown, but your particular question can be addressed by providing a [Minimum, Complete, verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In short, what you're referring to is probably the canvas widget, which supports drawing labels without a background color.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand of my own research on this topic under a different context, this is not possible. It is possible to change the transparency of an entire window, but not individual widgets. The linked post mentions using a canvas as a background so that the text created has no background. You would also have to place all of your widgets on the canvas using the `Canvas.create_window` method:

```
root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(width=, height=, bg=, ...)

canvas.create_text(x, y, ...) # for text

entry = Entry(root, ...)
canvas.create_window(window=entry) # to place widgets on canvas
...
```

You would have to modify much of your code to accommodate for the canvas acting as your root, but I believe it can be done.

[Documentation for Canvas](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm)